# How to initialise view in fragment class in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I would like the equivalent code for the line below in Kotlin:

```
TextView tv = view.findViewbyId(R.id.textView);
```

Any help?

Comment: val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

Comment: val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simply, just do following action

```
val valueName = view!!.findViewById<ObjectName>(R.id.ObjectId)
```

also with this mark `!!` kotlin will be checked null state

finally see following example

```
val btn = view!!.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
```

Comment: I think, that's a mistake. If view will be null (it often happens), an application will crash. So, instead of `view!!` it should be written as `view?`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use Kotlin Android Binding? Which is an Extension from Kotlin helps to bind the view without any "bindView" or findViewById code to interfere business logic.

Once you have dig into it, you would definitely find it great and less code written afterwards.

Worth to have a look. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

---

But you can still use the original one with kotlin

```
val lblLabel = findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
```

Comment: by far the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of view in fragment :

```
val manageAddress=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

```
 val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
```

if you want to declare textview globally, use  `lateinit var tv: TextView`

Answer (score 0):

like this you can do in kotlin

```
val lv = findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Initialization:

```
val tv = findViewbyId(R.id.textView) as TextView
```

Refer [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/learn-kotlin-while-developing-an-android-app-part-2-e53317ffcbe9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
val myLabel = findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView
```

However you can use the **Kotlin Android Extensions** plugin.

Just add to your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then you can avoid the use of the `findViewById` method just using for example:

```
textView.text = "My text"
```

You can access the view without finding it or using third
party libraries just using the `id` assigned in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kotlin Android Extensions (`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`, see https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/), you can write `textView` and IDE will offer several variants of that view in different layouts. After you choose a right one, you can write something like:

```
textView.text = "This is a text"
```

In imports you will see something like `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dialog.*`